# ERROR NioEndpoint Socket accept failed java.io.IOException: Too many open files

Tags: sonarqube

After updating SonarQube to v5.3 (configuration adopted from the previous version we used, v5.1) we're getting the following error which stops SQ from running:

```
2016.02.16 00:26:11 ERROR web[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=<my-project-id> | id=AVLnP-hq9AOM7J73mzYa | time=13ms
2016.02.16 00:26:14 ERROR web[o.a.t.u.n.NioEndpoint] Socket accept failed
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:688) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
```

This error appears every 1-2 days.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: We solved the problem by a modification on Linux machine where SQ is running. 

`ulimit (old): 1024  / ulimit (new): 8192`

Answer (score 0):

Operate System treat network connections as a file,every connection is a  file descriptor.So i suggest you to check open files limit of system.